# How to alert user to correct input fields in form validation using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have this snippet code that will display some error in the `span` tag whenever the user will input an incorrect field. Instead of using `required`, when the user leaves it empty, I want my submit form to validate and display an `alert` message saying `'Please check and input correct fields'` before submitting. If the user will input some correct data, it will display a message `'Form Ok'`. Is there any proper way to execute this? Pass the function `onsubmit="return validateForm();"`.

Please help.

```js
function validateForm()
{
 //Prompts the to correct all fields. How??
}

//Checks password function
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#createpassword").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#confirmpassword").val();

    if ((password && confirmPassword) == "") {
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("");
    } else if (password != confirmPassword) {
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Password do not match!");
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").css("color", "red");
    } else {
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Password match.");
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").css("color", "green");
    }
}
//trigger keyup event in function checkPasswordMatch
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#createpassword, #confirmpassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});

//Add an Email Regular Expression and pass it to function validate
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

//Email Validate function
function validate() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    if (validateEmail(email)) {
        $("#checkEmail").text("");
    } else 
    {
        $("#checkEmail").text("Please enter a valid email address");
        $("#checkEmail").css("color", "red");
    }
}
//Call the function validate in blur event Jquery
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#email").blur(validate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="SignupProcess.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm();" id="signupform">
        <fieldset>
          
          <!-- Email Address field -->
          <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" type="email" required>
              <span id="checkEmail"></span>
          </div>
 
          <!-- Password input button -->
          <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Create Password"  name="createpassword"  oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a password')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" id="createpassword" type="password" required>
          </div>
          
           <!-- Confirm password input button -->
          <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmpassword" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please match your password')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" id="confirmpassword" type="password" required>
              <span class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch"></span>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Submit input button -->
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" id="signup" name="signupsubmit" class="btn btn-info form-control" value="Register">
          </div>
          
        </fieldset>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `alert` before `submit`?

Comment: Yes sir, it will alert before submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `onsubmit` in the form add replace it using the codes below:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
  //validate form
  var condition = validateForm(); //return true or false
  if(condition){
    alert('Form OK!');
  }
  //stop submission
  else{
    alert('Please check and input correct fields!');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: I did not quite understood your explanation sir, could you provide a code snippet to elaborate more?

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano basically you can perform all the validation inside the `jQuery .submit()` function. It all happens right after the form is triggered to submit and before it is sent to server. `Return false` and `preventDefault()` will stop the form from submitting.

Comment: But if the alert('Form Ok!'); sir , it will not proceed and submit. Instead, it will go to else condition 'Please check and input correct fields!' even though input fields are correct. Why is that? my form action="SignupProcess.php"  is submitting the data and save it into db.

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano I have edited my answer. Please try and see whether it works or not? Sorry it was my mistake for making it an infinite loop as the check and submit will loop infinitely

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a good coder but maybe this works.

The only thing you need is to switch your if else statement at enail validation so the false action is that it is good like at the password check.

Ihope it helped

```
if(checkPasswordMatch() && validate() == 0 ){
// custom alert here;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this would help

```
    function validateForm() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
       if (email == null || email == "") {
         alert("email must be filled out");
         return false;
       }
   }
```

if you have more than one input field with id email then add atrribute name to the form and you can do this

```
   function validateForm() {
      var email = document.forms["reqForm"]["email"].value;
    if (email == null || email == "") {
       alert("email must be filled out");
     return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: But what if I pass the alert message like 'please enter valid email address' on the function validate(); sir? How would you do it instead of alerting the user when input field is empty?